# How to show all employees Except one using Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

```
IEnumerable<ViewEmployees> us = from u in db.Users
                          join s in db.Designations
                          on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = s.DesignationID }

                          select new ViewEmployees
                          {
                           EmployeeName = u.Name,
                           EmployeeID = u.Id,
                           EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
                           Designation = u.DesignationID,
                           DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
                          };
```

it shows all the records but i want to see all records except 1.. which is current user id

Comment: ...`where u.Id != CurrentUser.Id`...

Comment: What you mean be `current user id`?

Comment: Why you create an anonymous type for equality comparison?

Comment: thnx @jehof..
it is working for me now...!!!!

Comment: i didnt mean to write it...
it just giving an error dnt knw why..
then i use the anonymous type which is working for me... @HamletHakobyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<ViewEmployees> us = from u in db.Users
                          join s in db.Designations
                          on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = 
                          s.DesignationID }
                          Where u.Id != LoggedInUserId
                          select new ViewEmployees
                          {
                           EmployeeName = u.Name,
                           EmployeeID = u.Id,
                           EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
                           Designation = u.DesignationID,
                           DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
                          };
```

Answer (score 0):

use the where clause in the linq to filter out/in the list